# flutter visibility error and initState problem

Tags: laravel, flutter

i'm a beginner and i have a strange errori got a problem in visibility i work with laravel api if i have no products in database this.widget.client always false , if i have a product in database the application works perfectly !!
flutter code :

```
    bool client=false ;
    _getAuthenticatedUser() async {
          SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          var log = new Logger();
          var x = _prefs.getString('photoUser');
          this.widget.photo=json.decode(x);
          this.widget.name= json.decode(_prefs.getString('Username'));
          if(_prefs.getString('token')!=null){
            if(json.decode(_prefs.getString('role'))=='superAdmin'){
              this.widget.superAdmin=true;}else{this.widget.superAdmin=false;}
            if(json.decode(_prefs.getString('role'))=='admin'){
              this.widget.admin=true;
            }else{this.widget.admin=false;}
            if(json.decode(_prefs.getString('role'))=='user'){
              _prefs.setString('client', 'client');
              this.widget.client=true;
            }else{this.widget.client=false; log.d('here not client');}
      }
      else{
               this.widget.superAdmin=false;
              this.widget.admin=false;
              this.widget.client=false;
      }
      }
 _getAllProducts() async {
     var _productService = ProductService();
     var products = await _productService.getProducts();
    var result = json.decode(products.body);
    var log = new Logger();
    _productList.clear();
    result.forEach((data) {
      var product = Product();
       product.id = data['id'] ?? 0 ;
      product.name = data['name'] ?? "";
      product.photo = data['photo'] ?? "";
      product.price = data['price'] ?? 0;
      product.discount = data['discount'] ?? 0;
      product.detail = data['detail'] ?? 'No detail';
      product.quantity = data['quantity'] ?? 0;
      setState(() {
          _productList.add(product);
      });
    });
  }
    @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        _getAuthenticatedUser();
        _getAllProducts();}
    and in the build
    Visibility(
                      visible: this.widget.client,
                      child:  ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.category,color: Colors.white,),
                          title: Text('Produits refusé',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>RefusedProducts(_refusedProductList,this.widget.client,this.widget.photo,this.widget.name)));
                          }
                      ),),
```

Comment: You need to check about `setState` and how to use it for updating the value.

Comment: The is problem is when i pass the _productList empty to another screen

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `setState()` function like this:

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    setState(() {
          _productList.add(product);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , Same problem,the is problem is when i pass the _productList empty to another screen

Comment: You're calling `SetState()` for every product item. It means you rebuild the widget many times for nothing. Anyway, you really need to go through some tutorials.